# Binding to a property from a DataModel to its parent ViewModel?

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, datagrid, mvvm

I'm using the M-V-VM pattern.
I have a ViewModel and an ObservableCollection of DataModels.
The list of DataModels are data-bound to a DataGrid.

When the grid is rendered, i would like one of the fields to be a ComboBox (let's say a list of string names).

This string name list is a common list that applies to all rows (i.e. DataModels).

Is there a way to bind a grid's field-level row property to the parent ViewModel?

One possible solution that i'd like to avoid is this:
Have a get-property in the DataModel that essentially returns the ViewModel's property (the list of string names).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it with a static resource.
E.g. define your static resource in xaml

```
<UserControl.Resources>
   <mynamespace:MyViewModel x:Key="MyViewModel" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Now you can reference this resource in your user control:

```
<Controls::DataGrid DataContext="{StaticResource MyViewModel}" ItemSource="{Binding MyItems}" ...
  <Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems, Source={StaticResource MyViewModel}" DisplayMemberPath="MyString" /> <!-- This does the job with the combo box and the strings -->
    </DataTemplate>
  </Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</Controls:DataGrid>
```

Hope this helps,

BR,

TJ

Comment: So i guess the binding property doesn't traverse thru the entire DataContext tree (child model to parent viewmodel) if it can't find the property in the current DataContext? Let me try this out though!

Comment: When i add the staticresource ref to the viewmodel, my viewmodel is being created twice. The problem is that im creating the viewmodel in the view's constructor (as opposed to defining it in the xaml).

Comment: Yes, as soon as the <mynamespace:MyViewModel x:Key="MyViewModel" /> is parsed the object will be created. You have several opportunities here. E.g.you make it a Singleton and add it to the App resources on startup Application.Current.Resources.Add("MyViewModel", MyViewModel.Instance);), or you reference the created object via the application resources((MyViewModel)Application.Current.Resources["MyViewModel"];)
Does this help you?